# Position fixed within overflow container - scrollToFixed

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use a plugin called [scrollToFixed](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) to fix headers on scroll, much like the iOS contacts list. I can't see how I can make the headers (.learning-objective-header) fixed and relative to the container though.

```
    <div class="panel-container">
  <div class="title">Assessment - Year 1 - Summer Half Term</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <select><option>English 80%</option></select>
      <button class="submit-btn">Send Assessment</button>
    </div>
    <div class="column-container">
      <div class="review-screen-wrapper">
        <div class="review-screen perfect-scroll">
          <div class="learning-objective-header">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-1 learning-objective-label">Writing</th>
                  <th class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive">I can</th>
                  <th class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral">Nearly there</th>
                  <th class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative">I need help</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="learning-objective-body">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="learning-objective-header">
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="col-1 learning-objective-label">Writing</th>
                  <th class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive">I can</th>
                  <th class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral">Nearly there</th>
                  <th class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative">I need help</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="learning-objective-body">
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="col-1 sub-learning-objective-label">Can I use a captial letter?</td>
                  <td class="col-2 marking-scheme-positive"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-3 marking-scheme-neutral"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                  <td class="col-4 marking-scheme-negative"><span class="marking-scheme-input"></span></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

@import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700";
.panel-container ,
.panel-container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #014783;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
.panel-container {
  background: #006bb3;
  border: 2px solid #b5e4fe;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
}
.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #0089da;
  padding: 15px 22px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.nav-bar {
  text-align: left;
}
.submit-btn {
  float: right;
}
.content {
  padding: 22px;
  position: relative;
}
.column-container:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.review-screen-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 22px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #444;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.review-screen {
}
.review-screen.perfect-scroll {
  height: calc(100vh - 184px);
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.review-screen table th,
.review-screen table td {
  padding: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: left;
}
.review-screen table th {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 13px 15px;
}
.learning-objective-header ~ .learning-objective-header table th.col-1 {
  border-top: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
}
.review-screen table th.col-1 {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CBCBCB;
}
.learning-objective-header ~ .learning-objective-header table .col-1 {
  border-top: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}
.review-screen table .col-1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}
.learning-objective-header ~ .learning-objective-header table .col-2 {
  border-top: 1px solid #A7CB72;
}
.review-screen table th.col-2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A7CB72;
}
.review-screen table .col-2 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #BAE083;
}
.learning-objective-header ~ .learning-objective-header table .col-3 {
  border-top: 1px solid #E5C46D;
}
.review-screen table th.col-3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5C46D;
}
.review-screen table .col-3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EDD9A4;
}
.learning-objective-header ~ .learning-objective-header table .col-4 {
  border-top: 1px solid #F9959D;
}
.review-screen table th.col-4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F9959D;
}
.review-screen table .col-4 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F7AFB5;
}
.review-screen table .col-2,
.review-screen table .col-3,
.review-screen table .col-4 {
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}
.review-screen table .col-1 {
  background: #FFF;
}
.review-screen table .col-2 {
  background: #ddecd5;
  color: #81a34f;
}
.review-screen table .col-3 {
  background: #fdeec7;
  color: #be9424;
}
.review-screen table .col-4 {
  background: #fecacc;
  color: #d16972;
}
.review-screen .learning-objective-body tr:last-child .col-1,
.review-screen .learning-objective-body tr:last-child .col-2,
.review-screen .learning-objective-body tr:last-child .col-3,
.review-screen .learning-objective-body tr:last-child .col-4 {
  border: 0 none;
}
.marking-scheme-input {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 12px solid #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.125);
  border-radius: 24px;
  display: block;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.marking-scheme-input:after {
  content: " ";
  display: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  left: -9px;
  border: 9px solid currentColor;
}
.marking-scheme-input:not(.active):hover:after {
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.marking-scheme-input.active:after {
  display: block;
}
.ps-container>.ps-scrollbar-y-rail>.ps-scrollbar-y {
  background-color: #343434;
}
.ps-container:hover>.ps-scrollbar-y-rail:hover>.ps-scrollbar-y {
  background-color: #343434;
}
.ps-container.ps-in-scrolling.ps-y>.ps-scrollbar-y-rail>.ps-scrollbar-y {
  background-color: #343434;
}

$('.learning-objective-header').scrollToFixed();
```

http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/3bc99200b9d501c329608a153f63fde6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that plugin provides a way to handle relative fixed positioning. It does, however, give the option to absolutely position the fixed element based on the location of the top and bottom of the screen. So if you know the height of the area above the fixed element, you can simply use the marginTop option to set the position, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.learning-objective-header').scrollToFixed({
    marginTop: 137
  });
});
```

Here it is in action in a modifed Codepen: http://codepen.io/pen/rVpqpz

Comment: Ah ok that seems to do the trick. How come it doesn't change the fixed header to the next header? http://codepen.io/2ne/pen/3e45c7c75046070b2f14546b2afe0605

Comment: There is also an option to set a "limit", based on the height of the page, which indicates when to begin re-scrolling the fixed element. Presumably then, and only then, can the appropriate class transfer to the next element in line, which also must have a marginTop set. It's really not a very flexible plugin. Be sure to refer to all the options at the bottom of the documentation: https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed.

Comment: I have found that what i need is a position sticky polyfill that works within an overflow container